# Change $_FILES file name before upload (to wordpress media library)

Tags: php, wordpress, post, file-upload

I have a html form sending to php script with "post" method (no ajax involved).

In the form i have some `type="file"` fields.

Now in my php script i have a php foreach loop looping through the sent files:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file => $value) {
// Some checks and actions.
}
```

and i upload each one of the files (after some checks) with the wordpress `media_handle_upload` function like that:

```
media_handle_upload( $file, $newpost_id );
```

What i want to do is change the file name before uploading it to wordpress. so there are some answers about how to do that when using the `move_uploaded_file()` function but they don't seam to work for my situation. so i tried:
`$value['name'] = 'mynewfilename.png';` but that also doesn't seam to work. any ideas?

Note: I know i have to deal with the ext when changing the file name. i got that part covered, so focusing on the main issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uploading the file with the php move_upload_file function which let's you change the file name. then create the different sizes and id and all with Wordpress's `wp_insert_attachment`, `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` and letting wordpress know about that with `wp_update_attachment_metadata`.

It's a shame Wordpress doesn't let you handle files more easy and customized.